# When is Session State ready for use in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state, global-asax

I have an asp.net site, where in i am checking session variable in `Global.asax` in `Application_BeginRequest` but it always says `object reference not set to an instance of an object`, i don't understand this, because i am checking the condition for null before using the value, but still it throws the above error, however when i check it inside the `default.aspx Page_Load` event it works properly without any issues.

Can anyone tell whats the problem behind this, am i not supposed to use the session variable inside `Application_BeginRequest`

If yes, then how i will be checking the session value, what i want to achieve is, if user is logged in (If Session["Login"] is not empty means user logged in) and has the rights to access the page, then allow him/her else throw him to the homepage.

Here is what i am doing.
Below function checks for if user is logged in:

```
public static String LoggedInUser
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Login"] == null)
                return String.Empty;
            else
                return HttpContext.Current.Session["Login"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Login"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Below function checks if user has right to access the page:

```
public static bool IsPageAllowed(String Pagename)
{
    bool _isPageAllowed = false;
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Pagenames.xml"));
    if (LoggedInUser != String.Empty)
    {
        XmlNodeList list = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/AllPages/Pages[@user='" + GetLoggedInUserRole(Globals.LoggedInUser).ToLower() + "']/Page[contains(text(), '" + Pagename + "')]");
        if (list.Count > 0)
            _isPageAllowed = true;
    }
    return _isPageAllowed;
}
```

And below function is used on `Application_BeginRequest` to redirect user based on their rights:

```
if (!Globals.IsPageAllowed(rawUrl.Substring(1, rawUrl.Length - 1)))
        {
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Session state is available during and after appropriately named [HttpApplication.PostAcquireRequestState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postacquirerequeststate(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Occurs when the request state (for example, session state) that is associated with the current request has been obtained.

Full sequence of events with descriptions is available somewhere on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx and other sites like [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/05/27/asp-net-application-life-cycle.aspx?Redirected=true)

Shortened list of events below (many events are omitted, see MSDN link for details):

- `BeginRequest`
- `AuthenticateRequest`
- `AcquireRequestState`
- `PostAcquireRequestState`
- `ProcessRequest` method (or the asynchronous version `IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest`) of the appropriate IHttpHandler class for the request. For example, if the request is for a page, the current page instance handles the request.

Note that session state is not available till at least `AcquireRequestState` (where it may be available if `SessionStateModule` managed to receive that event before your code). There is no way `Session` will be available during `BeginRequest`.

Note that there are explicit authentication events that should be used if you need authentication/authorization (also it is not usable for your case as you keep auth information in session state).

Comment: i tried using Application_AcquireRequestState event and initiate my session (Session["Login"] there), but still in Application_BeginRequest, i gets the object reference error.

Comment: @Abbas - have you checked MSDN link I've posted? The BeginRequest event happens way before `PostAcquireSessionState`, so I'm not sure why do you expect `Session` to be present that early during request lifetime.